# Postgresql can I access inline array items returned from function?

Tags: postgresql

Say I have a function which returns an array. Can I access its items inline inside a select query? I can not use sub-querying since function relies on query parameters. And I can not declare outside variable for the same reason.

I expect somewhat like this:

```
select foo,bar, function(foo,bar)[1] as array_item_1, function (foo,bar)[2]  as array_item_2 from table...
```

Currently I return function(foo,bar) as array_items and iterate it in application which is really cumbersome. I want db to return prepared outputs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I access its items inline inside a select query?

Yes, but you need an extra pair of parentheses ([as documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-EXPRESSIONS-SUBSCRIPTS))

```
select foo, bar, 
       (function(foo,bar))[1] as array_item_1, 
       (function(foo,bar))[2] as array_item_2 
from table...
```

However, unless the function is defined as stable or immutable, each expression **will** call the function. So in the above, if the function is defined as `volatile` (the default!) then it would be called twice. In that case using a derived table is a better approach:

```
select foo, bar, 
       result[1] as array_item_1, 
       result[2] as array_item_2 
from ( 
  select foo, bar, function(foo,bar) as result
  from table...
) as t
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :)